# Is there a way to extract the height from each leaf of a dendrogram in R?

Tags: r, dendrogram, hclust, dendextend

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZrBF.png)

From this dendrogram, I would like to extract the height for each leaf.
In this case example, I would like to get back a list like this :

```
list("A" = 2.07, "B" = 5.09, "C" = 3.12, "D" = 2.07, "E" = 3.12)
```

Here's the code for this example:

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(30), nrow = 5)
rownames(m) <- LETTERS[1:5]
d <- dist(m)

h <- hclust(d)
plot(h)
```

I can extract the height from the dendrogram easily with

```
h$height
```

And see the information I want with

```
str(as.dendrogram(h))
```

But I couldn't find a way to extract what I want. I also looked into the `dendextend` package but I couldn't find what I want.
Do you know a function that already does this? I'm not very familiar with S3 objects...

Comment: Do you want `library(dendextend);get_branches_heights(as.dendrogram(h))`

Comment: No, because unfortunately it doesn't return the corresponding labels

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`dendextend`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/dendextend.html) package to first convert it to a `as.dendrogram` object. After that you can extract the labels with the `labels` function. To get the heights of the labels you first convert it with `hang.dendrogram` and then extract the height attribute of the leaves using `get_leaves_attr` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dendextend)

set.seed(7) # reproducibility
m <- matrix(rnorm(30), nrow = 5)
rownames(m) <- LETTERS[1:5]
d <- dist(m)
h <- hclust(d)
plot(h)
```

[image]

```r
dend <- as.dendrogram(h)
labels = dend %>% labels
heights = dend %>% hang.dendrogram %>% get_leaves_attr("height")
data.frame(labels = labels,
           heights = heights)
#>   labels   heights
#> 1      E 2.3400492
#> 2      B 0.9012174
#> 3      C 0.9012174
#> 4      A 3.3943293
#> 5      D 3.3943293
```

If you want to have it in a list you could `setNames` with `as.list` like this:

```r
as.list(setNames(heights, labels))
#> $E
#> [1] 2.340049
#> 
#> $B
#> [1] 0.9012174
#> 
#> $C
#> [1] 0.9012174
#> 
#> $A
#> [1] 3.394329
#> 
#> $D
#> [1] 3.394329
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>